# clipping spatial files in R

Tags: r-sp, r-maptools

I am currently trying to clip one spatial file to another however the spatial file I get is not the right shape. I know with a raster you have to use a mask, is there a similar command for 2 shape files?

```
c1 <- crop(spatial1, spatial2)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the SpatialPolgyonDataFrame objects

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
b <- as(extent(6, 6.4, 49.75, 50), 'SpatialPolygons')
crs(b) <- crs(r)
```

You can do

```
pc <- crop(p, b)
```

You need to have packages `rgdal` and `rgeos` installed.